# Converting GMT grid to ArcGIS readable format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion, gmt

I am trying to convert a GMT grid [data](http://igpppublic.ucsd.edu/~gabi/ftp/sediment.tar.gz) into a format that is readable in ArcGIS. I have already attempted to load the data into GRASS and use GDAL translate to convert into a tif with unwanted results. Mainly the extent is wrong with a cell size of 1,1 while in reality it should cover the entire world.

***Update***

After installing GMT and utilizing the source code

```
grd2xyz -Ef input.grd
```

the resulting ascii grid was converted to a tif format that was read by ArcGIS (ascii to raster). However again the final product does not have a correct extent showing a cellsize of 1,1. Could someone who perhaps is more familiar with GMT check the data above to check if it is viable to use within an ArcMap format?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this tool: http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/pi/MB-System/

It can convert GMT grid to ascii, then you can use other software, like FME, to convert to esri grid. (Found this info in the following pdf, chapter 3.3.2: https://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ngdc.noaa.gov%2Fdem%2FsquareCellGrid%2FgetReport%2F296&ei=wk7ZUN7WC47YsgbfiICIDg&usg=AFQjCNGtIdoQf6SuZAYt4wqr5hUPkR9TOQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms)

Comment: I have tried to convert between GMT to ascii and then converting to a tiff but the resulting extent is still not correct