# How to convert *.shp files to *.gmt format type files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, gmt

I am new at using GMT ([Generic Mapping Tools](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/)) and I am wondering if it can use a shapefile of a hydrographical network.

Can I perhaps change my .shp to .gmt format and combine it with a GMT map? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GMT grid to ESRI readable format](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/gmt-grid-to-esri-readable-format)

Comment: I think this is the exact opposite

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain the GMT abbreviation, please?

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo. Also network shapefile? You mean a group of shape files to load into something? I have never heard of a network shapefile in esri.

Comment: @BradNesom I think "hydrographical network shapefile" will be a line shapefile of a hydrographic network.  GMT could be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Mapping_Tools.  In any event I think this question should be focussed on the conversion and the extra parts researched/asked separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert from shape to gmt use [this](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)
example code :

> `ogr2ogr -f "GMT" Hudson_bounds.gmt  Hudson_bounds.shp`

Comment: how can i use this? at my command prompt? please can you help me i can understand it

Comment: @Fotini_M you can get the ogr2ogr commandline tool by installing [GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries#Windows)

Comment: Type it from youre command prompt window, link was provided by Luke.

Answer (score 0):

In GDAL 2.2.1 the call is:

> `ogr2ogr -f "OGR_GMT" Hudson_bounds.gmt  Hudson_bounds.shp`

Answer (score 0):

Shapefiles can be converted to xy segment files using QGIS. Just right click on the shapefile in QGIS and then Save As -> Format "Generic Mapping Tools [GMT]". Use WGS84 as the CRS, give a file name and click OK.

This is highly userfriendly when dealing with multi segment shapefiles.

Comment: Can't find this options at all in Qgis