# shapefile to gmt format

Tags: shapefile, dem, elevation, contour, gmt

I have an ESRI shapefile of the contours of my study area, and I want to convert it into a format that is acceptable by GMT, so I can make an elevation map of my study area. Is that even possible? 
Would it be easier, if I had a dem file, to convert it into gmt format?

Edit: I made a .dem file. How can I convert it to GMT acceptable type?

Comment: This is very similar to an earlier question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107325/how-to-convert-shp-files-to-gmt-format-type-files Perhaps one or both can be edited to makes the difference between them clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well make a DEM/TIN (using ArcGIS) of the shapefile you have. That will give you the DEM you need to convert to GMT format.

After a quick Google search, I found a couple of links..

[convert SRTM30 data to grd](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gmt.user/20159)

[Shapefile to GMT DEM file](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-January/035363.html)

Also check the this PDF, mostly after the 15th Page - [GMT and Gridded Datasets](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~ecalais/teaching/gmt/GMT_6.pdf)

There is a clear cut procedure for convering the DEM data to GMT data. Conversion from shapefile to DEM is fairly simple, as you have already achieved it.

Comment: I made a *.dem file. Should I convert it to *.grid, to be able to use it at GMT? If so, how?

Comment: Check the remodified answer. There a bunch of useful links (credits to Google) for the solution. Tick my answer if sufficient, else will help you out further..