# Shapefile in gmt format

Tags: shapefile

I want to save shapefile (polygon) with color in gmt format and in geoghrapic coordinate not UTM. Mmy shapefile is in UTM. I run below as an example how to show in lat lon and with color.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GMT" Hudson_bounds.gmt  Hudson_bounds.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1. Shapefiles don't store color. That's usually stored in the program using them.

2. If your data is in UTM, re-project it to Geographic (wgs-84) before you convert it.
3. Use ogr2ogr  or an on-line converter to convert the shapefile.
   https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-gml

This link might help... [How to convert *.shp files to *.gmt format type files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107325/how-to-convert-shp-files-to-gmt-format-type-files?rq=1)